# How to define a regular expression for checking in Access?

Tags: regex, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have created a database in access and I want the value of a field to accept values as follows:

*capitalCharacters-numbers*

How can I define a regular expression for this case?
I use Access 2003. I tried the *Like ("[A-Z]*-*[0-9]")*, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: Exactly where did you use that expression? Have you explored textbox InputMask property?

Comment: Hi Yunnosch. I delete a question when I realize from the comments that it might be redundant and won't help someone in the future, not when I find the solution.

Comment: Fair point, which I might have missed. Good style still reacting to my input here. Have fun.